# A shoujo manga about a girl who cuts a guy's hair in the middle of class and later fixes it

Tags: kyou-koi-wo-hajimemasu

This manga is about a high school girl who loves doing her sister's hair in the mornings, but she doesn't do her own hair because she thinks it won't suit her. One day at school, she cuts a guy's hair in the middle of class. Later she fixes it, and then the story progresses. That's all I can remember, thank you.

Comment: where does this story progress to?

Comment: Well they get closer and closer as he protects her from jealous girls in the school. That's all I remember sorry

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you name this shoujo manga?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6924/can-you-name-this-shoujo-manga)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm quite sure it is [**Kyou, Koi o Hajimemasu**](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=12294). Your description matches the details from chapter 1 of the manga.

[image: Volume 1 Cover]

Synopsis from mangaupdates (emphasis mine):

> **Tsubaki is a girl who loves making her younger sister's hair pretty every morning, but she doesn't think that kind of style suits herself!** The day of her High School Beginning Ceremony, after she failed in being the top student (who usually makes the ceremony speech), she finds herself sitting next to the actual top student of the first years, the worst rude guy ever, Kyouta. **She ends up cutting his hair on purpose because of the bad things he says to her.** Kyouta demands that Tsubaki pay him back with her body, but **Tsubaki fixes his hair instead--making it even shorter!** After that, Kyouta unexpectedly kisses Tsubaki and swears that he'll make her his woman.

#### Reference

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ky%C5%8D,_Koi_o_Hajimemasu)

Comment: I've been looking for this manga forever.thank you so much!